# heroku local does not find pdo_postgres driver

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, heroku, nginx

I am trying to use heroku local on mac to run a Symfony project. But unfortunately it does not find the postgresql driver... which is found when I run `php app/console server:run`

Here is the resulting output.

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'web/'
web.1  | Using Nginx server-level configuration include 'nginx_app.conf'
web.1  | PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
web.1  | 4 processes at 128MB memory limit.
web.1  | Starting php-fpm...
web.1  | [14-Oct-2015 14:19:20] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
web.1  | Starting nginx...
web.1  | Application ready for connections on port 5000.
web.1  | [14-Oct-2015 12:19:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Users/developpeur/Web/hm-gmao/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see these ?

http://www.somacon.com/p520.php
http://www.unixmen.com/solved-php-warning-module-pdo-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0/

Point is that if you have postgres compiled into php already, and you also try to load it in php.ini. you'll get the error.
Fix is to disable the modules in php.ini.